# Piecewise Symmetric Functions

Tags: functions

I am unclear as to what precisely is a symmetric function if it is defined piecewise.

For example, (in Maple) is

```
         A := (x, y) -> piecewise(x < y, 2*x-y, y < x, x-2*y, x = y, 0)
```

a symmetric function? And if so, why?.

Also, (in Maple) is

```
        B := (x, y) -> piecewise(x < y, x-(1-x)*y, y < x, -y+x*(1-y), x = y, 0)
```

a symmetric function. And if so, why?

My understanding is that a function is symmetric if f(a,b) = f(b,a) for all a, b. Is this correct?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, defining a symmetric function by $f(a,b)=f(b,a)$ is very reasonable. If a formula for $f$ is given piecewise, 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} g(x,y) \quad & \text{if } \ x<y; \\
h(x,y) \quad & \text{if } \ x>y; \\
k(x) \quad & \text{if } \ x=y \end{cases}  
$$
then the symmetry requirement amounts to $g(x,y)=h(y,x)$. What $k$ is does not matter.

The two examples you gave satisfy a different identity, $f(a,b)=-f(b,a)$. Such functions are called *antisymmetric*. In the above notation, the antisymmetry requirement amounts to $g(x,y)=-h(y,x)$, and   $k$ being identically zero.